# How do I resolve an "Arg_NullReferenceException" error when trying to connect through CheckPoint VPN?

Tags: vpn, checkpoint

I use CheckPoint VPN to log in to my place of work's servers to work remotely.  The VPN has been working (mostly) fine all year, and I haven't changed any of the settings, but this morning, when I tried to log in, it's giving me the "Arg_NullReferenceException."  I can't seem to find anything on this particular error on google.

I have tried restarting my computer, because it's not the first issue I've had with CheckPoint VPN (though it is the first time I've seen that error message), and a restart usually resolves whatever issue I'm having.  I've also tried creating a new connection with the same settings, but I'm getting the same error with that one, too.

I'm not entirely sure what other information I would need to provide.  I'm also not sure if it's a problem on my end, or on the company servers.  I have already emailed tech support, but I thought I should be thorough.

Comment: Have tech support come back to you?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.  I have been jumping through hoops trying to get the capsule client to work.  Raise a ticket with TAC if you have support.  If not then you can download the E86 Endpoint connect client and run it.  That has been my work around for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

They just issued an update to the Capsule via the Microsoft Store. It seems one of the recent Windows Security Update broke the L2TP protocol within windows.